# Stripping the domain name from a url using SQL

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery

I'm working with Big Query's Hacker News dataset, and was looking at which urls have the most news stories. I'd also like to strip the domain names out, and see which of those have the most news stories. I'm working in R, and am having a bit of trouble getting the follow query to work.

```
# Select the ten domains that have the most stories
sql_domain <- "SELECT url REPLACE(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(url, '//') 
                        THEN url ELSE CONCAT('http://', url) END, '&', '?') as domain_name,
                      COUNT(domain_name) as story_number
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full`
                WHERE type = 'story'
                GROUP BY domain_name
                ORDER BY story_number DESC
                LIMIT 10"
```

I don't need to strip the top-level domain; for example, `stackoverflow` isn't required, `stackoverflow.com` is fine. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you want one of the net functions? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/net_functions#netreg_domain

Comment: @ElliotBrossard Very elegant! I'm trying:

  `sql_domain_ag <- "SELECT NET.REG_DOMAIN(url) as domain_name,
                      COUNT(domain_name) as story_number`

And am now getting "Error: Unrecognized name: domain_name at [2:29] [invalidQuery]" so I must be calling the function improperly, or something.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your query - you should use as below (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
SELECT 
  NET.REG_DOMAIN(url) AS domain_name,
  COUNT(NET.REG_DOMAIN(url)) AS story_number
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full`
WHERE type = 'story'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY story_number DESC
LIMIT 10
```

this will give you something like below

```
Row domain_name     story_number     
1   github.com      81784    
2   medium.com      71953    
3   youtube.com     58119    
4   blogspot.com    52925    
5   nytimes.com     48986    
6   techcrunch.com  43924    
7   google.com      26326    
8   wordpress.com   23372    
9   arstechnica.com 23162    
10  wired.com       18480
```